# Web App that Keeps Record of Words Learned By Users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, web-applications

I am trying to make a web app to learn chinese characters, and I want to keep record of the characters the users learn on a database.

I thought of keeping record using a `words_learned` column in the users table with an array that contains the `character_id` of the characers that already knows.

But I am a beginner so I don't know if this is efficient. Is the design right? Should I use many columns instead of an array? or is the complete design wrong?

Characters table

```
character_id   character   pinyin     meaning
1              我          wo3        i
2              你          ni3        you
3              他          ta1        he
.
.
.
600            山          shan1      mountain
```

Users table

```
user_id        user        password   words_learned
1              john        1234       {1, 5, 68, 599}
2              chuck       passwd     {2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 90, 160}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is normalized with *another* table, that would contain both a `user_id` and `character_id`.

This can be a huge table, but that's ok.